# Jquery clone doesnt copy all html

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-node, jquery-clone

Please advise how to make jquery below clone the full line, at the moment only "3" is inserted.

I would like the following inserted e.g

```
 <div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">3</div>
```

jquery:

```
var $clone = $('div.servline_vhc.servline_vhc_inspection.clearfix').last().clone(true);
$clone.insertAfter($('div.servline_vhc.servline_vhc_inspection.clearfix').last());
```

html:

```
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">1</div>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">2</div>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">3</div>
```

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/hy20rmrr/. Check the console for errors elsewhere in your code

Comment: Hi, just added 
console.log($clone.html()); and only shows "3"

Comment: That's correct. You only clone the last `div`. It's HTML content is just `'3'`. What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I need full line e.g
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">3</div>

Comment: You realise that the cloning is working, though? This is unrelated to your initial question

Comment: question updated TQ

Comment: Ok, now you updated your question. Again though, this is already doing what you describe. You realise that you'll only see the `3` in the output. The actual HTML code won't be shown in the browser. If you check the fiddle in my first comment you'll see that there are two divs containing `3`. The first is the original, the second is the clone. Your code is working fine

Comment: Thank you Rory - I wasn't sure the full line was being cloned. ps. is there a way to inspect the full output of clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood right that's what you want, check the console in the working example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  // Setting the clone
  var $clone =   $('div.servline_vhc.servline_vhc_inspection.clearfix').last().clone(true);
  
  // This already saves the last element node like you want
 $clone.insertAfter($('div.servline_vhc.servline_vhc_inspection.clearfix').last()); 
  
  // Check the console, that's the element DOM node HTML
  console.log($clone[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">1</div>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">2</div>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">3</div>
```

If you just want the element, remind about the use of ".insertAfter()".

Some links from jQuery's offical documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

http://api.jquery.com/clone/